# jQuery: selecting all elements having class X except those also having class Y

Tags: jquery, selector

Is it possible in jQuery to select all elements having class X except those also having class Y? This is my code:

```
jQuery( '.class_A, .class_B' ).mCustomScrollbar();
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
jQuery( '.class_A, .class_B[except_if_also_has_class_C' ).mCustomScrollbar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
$('.class_X:not(.class_Y)')
```

This will select all elements that have class A and not those which have both A and B

```js
$('.a:not(.b)').css({'color': 'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="a">a</li>
  <li class="a">a</li>
  <li class="a">a</li>
  <li class="a b">ab</li>
  <li class="b">b</li>
  <li class="b">b</li>
  <li class="a b">a</li>
  <li class="b">b</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you use the the jquery `.not()` functionality:

http://api.jquery.com/not/

you could do something like so:

```
$('.class_B').not('.class_C');
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by doing this

```
jQuery('[class="class_A class_B"]');
```

This will get you the class A and class B only.

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vywhghuf/)